# read mp3 file with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

i would like to read mp3 file with  AVAudioPlayer

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
AVAudioPlayer *player;

@property(retain,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;
@synthesize player

-(IBAction) lirepiste
{
    NSString *file =@"http://media.islamway.net/lessons/othymeen/40nowaweyya/1.mp3";
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:file,error:nil]; 
    [player play];
}
```

no error no crash but also no read

Answer (score 1):

Make your header file look like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UIScrollView *LLScrollView;
    AVAudioPlayer *data;
}
- (IBAction) playSound;
@end
```

and make the implementation look like this

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@implementation FirstViewController


- (IBAction) playSound {

    NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SoundName"];
    NSString *source = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (data) {
        [data stop];
        [data release];
        data = nil;
    }
    data=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: source] error:NULL];
    data.delegate = self;
    [data play];
    }

//everything else...


@end
```

If your sound file is named "example.mp3" then in initWithFormat only type "example" and the file name.

This code works flawlessly. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I did as you recommended to, but have got 2 errors:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  **"_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:**
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: **linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

what is wrong with it?

Comment: I forgot to add AVFoundation framework to my project, I'm sorry =)